# Tracking a backdoor by recording packets

Tags: network, logging, packet, backdoor

I am by **no** means very bright when it comes to networking. But I know a bit.

Let's say I suspect a backdoor is on my pc.
To counter it I setup a device between the router and my pc to log everything.

Would this work in the idea that I would eventually see some odd ip address?

Comment: Why don't you just simply use netstat to list out all the network connections on your system?

Comment: @adam86 On a potentially compromised system, `netstat` output would obviously be unreliable.

Comment: @Arminius why? Could you please explain?

Comment: The reason why I said a device in the middle is to capture EVERYTHING.

Comment: So with netstat you would not see some "odd ip addresses" connecting to your device?

Comment: You probably would for most backdoors.. However we are getting stuck on how to find it instead of the question itself.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your question. Why then not just installing Wireshark or using netsh to capture packets from your box instead of putting something between your box and the router, I don't get it.

Comment: @adam86 My malware shuts down as soon as your Wireshark starts up. Same with `netstat`. You can simply make the malware stop communicating as soon as the user starts up their network analysis tools. As a general rule, you can't reliable analyze malware from the same machine.

Comment: @Arminius that is very interesting. How would it know that I start Wireshark? By watching for it's process being executed? What about netstat, it's buil-in in the os... could you explain please?

Comment: Netstat is a command line tool

Comment: @adam86 That would be an option. You could also replace the `netstat` binary by a modified one that ignores the backdoor.

Comment: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx

Comment: @Beall619 yes I know, what I meant is, that you can do network captures with it same as with Wireshark

Comment: @Beall619 I think you might want to have a look at this http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-07&post=How-to-detect-reverse_https-backdoors  it explains how to possibly track this even without having to encrypt the traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this work in the idea that I would eventually see some odd ip address?

Generally, yes. If the malware is actively communicating, you will be able to capture the traffic and eventually conclude which servers it's contacting (and read the traffic if it's not encrypted).

The problem with your approach is that you can only confirm that there is malware if you *do* discover something. The reverse is not true. The backdoor could just remain inactive for an arbitrary amount of time. Also, chances are that you don't recognize malicious traffic as such:

A clever backdoor could be designed to only send traffic if other processes are communicating at the same time. For example, if you are browsing the web, it is really hard to dissect all connections for all loaded resources. Your backdoor could just mimick a request to an image hosted on a seemingly unsuspicious AWS server and it would be hard for you to tell if that request originated from your web browser or the backdoor. Also, it is possible for malware to evade detection by using seemingly unrelated protocols, e.g. DNS or ICMP. Finally, malware [is often communicating over TLS](https://blogs.cisco.com/security/malwares-use-of-tls-and-encryption) and you will have to be able to decrypt the traffic for definitive conclusions about what is going on.

So capturing all traffic will only lead to a conclusion under the assumption that the malware is actively communicating and that you are able to recognize  traffic by the backdoor as such.

Comment: Very interesting reading. So when you say that they use TLS for communication you mean for distribution of the malware itself or for the backdoor to communicate or perhaps both?

Comment: @adam86 I mean the way the malware communicates. The general point I'm trying to make here is that capturing malware communication isn't always straightforward as it can be obscured in different ways.

Comment: Yes, I see, I was not questioning your opinion by any means I wanted to know the why behind. So if they use TLS to communicate would this then mean that a certificate is stored for this on the victims computer for example in the CAPI store on MS OS ? Or is the backdoor writen in such a wat that it automatically will trust the server